# Are there branches of mathematics that are unique to String Theory?

Tags: string-theory, mathematics

I have read that String Theory has developed “new” math but the sources do not specifically identify the math. My question: are there branches of mathematics that are unique to String Theory?

Comment: In What are some significant contributions of string theory to other fields of physics?  Lubos Motl says:
String theory is the framework in which mirror symmetry was discovered; mathematicians have converted it into a subdiscipline of algebraic geometry that is studied by rigorous mathematical tools these days. Quite generally, much of algebraic geometry, especially topics related to Calabi-Yau manifolds, topology of higher-dimensional manifolds, K-theory, are using lots of tools that were first invented with the help of string theory – including topological string theory; ....